# PHP explode(), delimiter being returned?

Tags: php, explode

I'm not sure why but the explode function doesn't seem to be working for me.

I have a string which contains one or more sets of comma-seperated values. These sets are delimied by starting / ending square brackets.

After stripping off the ending "[" and "]", I thought it would be simple to then use the explode function to get the results seperated by "][". Instead, I get something weird.

```
$rawInserts = '[1,2,3,4,5][2,3,4,5,6][3,4,5,6,7]';
$the_inserts = substr($rawInserts,1,strlen($rawInserts)-2);
echo "$the_inserts \n"; //returns "1,2,3,4,5][2,3,4,5,6][3,4,5,6,7"
$inserts = explode($the_inserts , "][");
echo print_r($inserts)."\n"; // returns one item array containing "][";
```

why is it returning "]["? (FYI, I tried this exact example and it fails).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: rolled back; leave the question in place for others benefit

Comment: This is off-topic typo, right, @deceze?  They knew what they needed to do, they just failed in the implementation by reversing the parameters.

Comment: @mickmackusa you can't ping users that haven't contributed to the thing you're commenting on...

Comment: Ah, you are correct @Cer.  [Keep in mind that the question and answers are all considered independently.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/352329)

Answer (score 6):

```
array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )
```

Delimiter *first*, string *second*.

Comment: Thanks, sorry about the sillyness. I stared at the manual and it didn't pop out. Adding note to self: always double check parameter order.

Comment: This is off-topic: typo, right, @Deceze ?

Answer (score 1):

Switch the parameters. It's delimiter first and string as second parameter:

```
$inserts = explode('][', $the_inserts);
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be `$inserts = explode("][",$the_inserts );`

Answer (score -2):

I myself cannot remember the parameters for every function, so just go to the php.net website and search for the explode function.

Comment: I did actually, it just didn't pop out at me and it seemed the longer I stared the more I was sure I had everything right. Anyway, egg on my face.

Comment: This was not ment to be derogative. When you don't see what's wrong, start from the beginning. And that beginning is: Know how to call the function in the right way.